# JSF f:validateLength is processed after the converter, but need it before

Tags: java, jsf

I have a password inputfield where i have a md5 converter on it.
The field is binded with my `entity.password` field (that is stored as an md5 hash).

I want to set a `f:validateLength` on it so a password must have a certain length.
Problem is that a "" empty String has also an md5 hash. The validator doesn't check the actual input but the converted md5 hash.

Can i set the validator on the actual input, not the converted one?

```
<ice:inputSecret value="#{user.employer.user.password}" converter="md5hashconverter">
 <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="15"/>
</ice:inputSecret>
```

Thank you

**Edit:**
I'm using Hibernate and my backing bean is also the "model" managed bean. I persist with EntityManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

To me, this is also not really the right place to do the hash. It's not a "conversion" (which is supposed to be 2-way). Rather do it at the data access layer, either yourself right prior to `INSERT`, or just by grabbing the DB's builtin functions. Most of them provides sort of `MD5()` function which you can just use in your query like `INSERT INTO user (name, pass) VALUES (?, MD5(?))`.

**Edit**: as per the update, you're using Hibernate JPA. In this case you can either use JPQL to fire a "plain" save query with `MD5()` function inside, or to grab an [`EntityListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityListeners.html) ([guide here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html)) and act on `@PrePersist` and maybe also `@PreUpdate`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as always BalusC :)
I edited my post so you also know how i persist. I will re-think about where i do the hash. Inside the setter would be bad design?